# Date in RFC2822 to Apex DateTime?

Tags: apex, date, datetime, string, twilio

I'm getting some data from the Twilio API and one of the Date fields comes in this format

```
"Wed, 19 Nov 2014 00:41:08 +0000"
```

I've tried

```
Date.parse('Wed, 19 Nov 2014 00:41:08 +0000');

DateTime.parse('Wed, 19 Nov 2014 00:41:08 +0000');
```

also with valueOf and they all give me the same error message

```
Invalid format: "Wed, 19 Nov 2014 00:41:08 +0000"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any standard way to parse this, but here's a quick method to do it:

```
Map<String, String> months = new Map<String, String>
{
    'Jan' => '01',
    'Feb' => '02',
    'Mar' => '03',
    'Apr' => '04',
    'May' => '05',
    'Jun' => '06',
    'Jul' => '07',
    'Aug' => '08',
    'Sep' => '09',
    'Oct' => '10',
    'Nov' => '11',
    'Dec' => '12'    
};

public DateTime parseRFC2822(string input)
{
    List<string> parts = input.substring(input.indexOf(', ') + 2).split(' '), 
        dateparts = new List<String>{parts[2], parts[1],parts[0]},
        timeparts = parts[3].split(':');
    dateparts[1] = months.get(dateparts[1]);
    return DateTime.newInstanceGMT(integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]), 
                                   integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]),
                                   integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]),
                                   integer.valueOf(timeparts[0]),
                                   integer.valueOf(timeparts[1]),
                                   integer.valueOf(timeparts[2]));
}
```